# Graphics Problem During Instalation

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, usb-installation

I am trying to create a dual boot system using Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10. I resized the Windows 10 partition, created the unallocated space I need, etc. My problem is that when I try to boot into Ubuntu from USB to install it, I get the Ubuntu icon and then the screen becomes pretty fuzzy. It doesn't show something in particular, but random shapes and things on a blue screen. I imagine it is something with my graphics card. I have an AMD Radeon 7870. The same thing happens when I try to install Linux Mint. Tried the KDE and Cinammon versions, but still the same. How can I download a drive for Ubuntu if I cannot even start the installation process? I tried both the "Install Ubuntu" and "Try Ubuntu", installing the ISO image from other locations, but nothing worked. I have installed in the past an earlier version of Ubuntu in the same PC, with the same hardware configuration. What can I do?

Comment: When you first boot from the USB stick, at the screen which looks somewhat like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GtEi5.png), press Esc, and select "Try Ubuntu without installing" - if it doesn't, try booting with `nomodeset` as described in the first answer here: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](//askubuntu.com/q/162075)&lq=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried these options, booted into the boot screen which prompts me to enter my language to begin installation. But in this screen my mouse and keyboard don't work. I tried this in Mint too, the same thing happens. Is it an AMD problem?

Comment: The keyboard should work - use the arrow keys to navigate and enter to select things. You need to use the built in laptop keyboard or a USB keyboard though - bluetooth ones won't work. Read [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](//askubuntu.com/q/162075) for more info.